# Open UserForm, hide some command buttons in 1st page of multipages

Tags: vba, excel

I have a command button in excel that will open the userform

```
Sub openfile ()
  UserForms1.Show
End Sub
```

Now, how do I hide the command button on first page of the form then unhide it when the next page is selected?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "first page" and "next page" of the form. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Place the following into your UserForm_Initialize....
`Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False`.  Alternatively you can set the visible value of the button to false in properties window!

Then add this to the code for your UserForm

```
    Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
 If MultiPage1.Value = 1 Then   'page values start with 0 as the first page
   Me.CommandButton1.Visible = True
Else
    Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late response.